# ,How do I give an object a name via function argument?

Tags: javascript

I have a function like this:

```
function dataSend(type, message) {
  return {
    type: message
  };
};
```

Which I am using like this:

```
io.sockets.emit('addToQueue', dataSend('error', 'User not found'));
```

But when it gets to the client side I get an object that is like

`{ type: 'User not found' }`
instead of
`{ 'error': 'User not found' }`

Why is this acting like this? I'm not sure how to fix this any information would be great thanks.

Comment: With ES6 you can do `{[type]: message}`

Answer (score 3):

You can't set the key with a variable like that, you'll need bracket notation

```
function dataSend(type, message) {

   var obj = {};

   obj[type] = message;

   return obj;

};
```

Comment: Nah, happens all the time, don't sweat it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function dataSend(type, message) {
  var a={};
  a[type]=message;
  return a;
}
```

Javascript doesn't require quotes around the property names.

Using `{type:message}` or `{'type':message}` produces the same result.

Comment: Code–only answers aren't liked. You should add an explanation of why the OP failed and why your answer fixes it.

Comment: @RobG When you make `{type:message}`, you are creating the property `type`. Javascript doesn't require quotes around the property names.

Comment: I know the answer, I was commenting so you could make this and future answers better. :-)

Comment: @RobG Thanks for the tip. I totally had forgotten to do it.